# How do I label a list of lists sequentially?

Tags: algorithm, list, sequence

Suppose I have a sequence and a list of lists:

["A" "B" "C" "D" "E"]
[[:1 :2][:3 :4 :5]]

And I'd like to use the sequence to label each element of the list of lists:

[["A" :1 "B" :2] ["C" :3 "D" :4 "E" :5]]

What should my algorithm be?

---

Edit: So the best answer Stack Overflow can give is to make a copy and then mutate it, and that only works if the data is a specific shape?

I've accepted that answer since it's correct and the only answer given, but surely we can do better than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fairly simple. Iterate through your sublist elements while moving an index through the sequence. If the lists are longer than the sequence, you can use a modulo to set the moving index to the beginning of the sequence when it reaches the end.

```
int index = 0

for(sublist in list) {
    for(element in sublist) {
        element.label = sequence[index++]
        index = index modulo length_of(sequence)
    }
}
```

If your sublists can also have sublists, then you would probably have to make a recursive method.